# How can I access windows desktop files by using ubuntu 20.4 (wsl)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

is there any one around who can assist me on how to access windows desktop files by using ubuntu 20.4 (wsl). Coz I have tried my best, but I failed.

I navigated through `ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop$t` and `ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Default$` but I didn't see any file or a hint, what I got is `Desktop.init` which is totally different to what I Am looking for.

I have tried to look for every where but nothing I got. here are the folders I have tried.

```
ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop$ la
desktop.ini
ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop$ cd ..
ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Public$ la
AccountPictures  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Libraries  Music  Pictures  Videos  desktop.ini
ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Public$ cd ..
ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users$ la
'All Users'   Default  'Default User'   Lenovo   Public   desktop.ini
```

And

```
ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Lenovo$ cd ..
ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users$ cd Default
ndevu-pc@NDEVU-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Default$ la
 AppData             NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TM.blf
'Application Data'   NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
 Cookies             NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
 Desktop             NetHood
 Documents           OneDrive
 Downloads           Pictures
 Favorites           PrintHood
 Links               Recent
'Local Settings'    'Saved Games'
 Music               SendTo
'My Documents'      'Start Menu'
 NTUSER.DAT          Templates
 NTUSER.DAT.LOG1     Videos
 NTUSER.DAT.LOG2
```

They are so many.